# How do I add a CSS class to the application view in Ember 2.7 or higher?

Tags: ember.js

Views are gone since Ember 2.0.0, but you could do this:

```
// app/views/application.js or app/application/view.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: []
});
```

Since Ember CLI 2.7 this workaround no longer works, looks like the views folder is now being ignored. However, the Ember inspector still shows this for the application view:

```
view:foobar@view:toplevel
```

And the HTML is:

```
<div id="ember420" class="ember-view">
  <h2>application</h2>
</div>
```

It still is a view, there must be a way to customize it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like the best option is to add a component to the application template. What makes it the best solution is that you don't need extra addons or hacks.

More context: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11486

```
// application template
{{#app-view-substitute}}
  {{outlet}}
{{/app-view-substitute}}
```

**Note:** Not convenient for a large app where other developers have already made assumptions about the level of nesting of the elements. This adds one more level to every single element and CSS, even when carefully crafted, might break. An alternative is to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187809/7852

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery (via Ember.$) to manually add the class at some point in the application's startup.  This will work:

```
// in app/routes/application.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  // ...
  activate() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    let root = Ember.getOwner(this).get('rootElement');
    Ember.$(root).addClass('my-custom-class');
  },
  // ...
});
```

Since you are asking about the application route, there is no need to *clean up* after this in the `deactivate` hook.

This is a specialization of something I've done to facilitate tweaking of styles depending on the current route.  Here's an instance initializer that will add a `route--xyz` class to the root element for the current route hierarchy:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

function toCssName(routeName) {
  return `route--${routeName.dasherize().replace(/\./g, '-')}`;
}

export function initialize(appInstance) {

  Ember.Route.reopen({
    activate() {
      this._super(...arguments);
      Ember.$(appInstance.rootElement).addClass(toCssName(this.routeName));
    },
    deactivate() {
      this._super(...arguments);
      Ember.$(appInstance.rootElement).removeClass(toCssName(this.routeName));
    }
  });

}

export default {
  name: 'css-route-name',
  initialize
};
```

With this initializer, the root element will always have the class `route--application` in addition to any other active routes.

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be solved via css:

```
body > .ember-view {
  height: 100%;
}
```

As jquery selector 'body > .ember-view' should work too

Comment: Yeah, that works for styling purposes. It is a little brittle though. There are edge cases where the first .ember-view is not the application view, my situation :/ But 99% can probably go with this.

Comment: Other trick that can be used is creating a special empty component that will change class of parent element using jquery and then hide/remove itself. Then you may include this component in application.hbs

Answer (score -1):

What I ended up doing is:

```
  // top level component rendered in the application template
  didInsertElement: function() {                                                   
    this._super(...arguments);                                                
    this._addIdAndCSSClassToApplicationView();                                               
  },                                                                                

  _addIdAndCSSClassToApplicationView: function() {                                                                             
    let root = Ember.getOwner(this).get('rootElement'); // Ember >= 2.3                       
    let applicationView = root.querySelector('.ember-view:first-child');            

    let idclass = 'myRequiredName';                                      
    applicationView.id = idclass;                                                   
    let classes = applicationView.className;                                        
    applicationView.className = classes + ' ' + idclass;                            
  }
```

Wrapping the outlet is cleaner, this is a hack, but it makes sense in a large app where other have already made assumptions about the levels of nesting in the app.

With Ember 2.2 I had to change the `root` line to something like this:

```
let root = Ember.$('.ember-application');
```